# user input in c

Tags: c, character

I cannot figure out how to take away a letter dependent on user input. For example, if I enter `b` the code should output `cdefghijklmno...` If I enter `c` the code should output `defghijklmno...` I just don't know where to do the math?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char letter;

    printf("Type one letter of alphabet and following letters will appear (lowercase): ");
    scanf_s("%c", &letter);

    if (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z'){
        printf("%c, valid entry!\n\n", letter);
        for (letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; ++letter){
            printf("%c ", letter);
        }
    } else {
        printf("%c, invalid entry.\n\n", letter);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "code can only be in c not c++" why do you tag c++ then?

Comment: I assumed someone that knows c++ could help

Comment: Fyi, `for (letter = 'a';...` you just threw away the character you read, now using the `letter` variable as a loop control var. Dunno if that was intentional, but it's odd.

Comment: @Ben: Not really. But apparently it is "nonsense tagging day".

Comment: @Olaf, it is annoying, i agree, the last one more than this one (tagged with `c` but using `std::string`).

Comment: K sorry I just said I was new, damn

Comment: @Mad, thats fine you will learn, but its a good lesson, dont tag questions tags that are unrelated. `c` and `c++` share a letter but in most ways are otherwise unrelated.

Comment: Alright, well thanks alot for the help!!! You guys are lifesavers

Comment: @Mad: Ignorantia legis non excusat. RTFM: [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I enter `b` the code should output `cdefghijklmno`... If I enter `c` the code should output `defghijklmno`... I just don't know where to do the math

- As [@Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1294207/ben) has suggested, change your `for` loop to :

  ```
  for (++letter; letter <= 'z'; ++letter)
  {
      printf("%c ", letter);
  }
  ```
- The reason of using `++letter` is to print the alphabets which come after the entered `letter` up to `z`
- This would do the job

---

further, *from [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276943/user-input-in-c#comment63973460_38276969):*

> To give the user repeated chances if input is **incorrect**

- using a while loop would be helpful :

  ```
  while( (scanf(" %c",&letter) == 1) && letter!='*')
  {
      if (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z')
      {
          printf("%c, valid entry!\n\n", letter);
          for (++letter; letter <= 'z'; ++letter)
          {
              printf("%c ", letter);
          }
          printf("\n\n");

          // break;
          // place the above break if you want to stop scanning after first successful entry
      }

      else
      {
          printf("%c, invalid entry.\n", letter);
          printf("try again\n\n");
      }
  }
  ```

  - this loop would continue till the use enters `*` *(an asterik)*
  - **Note :** `while( (scanf(" %c",&letter) == 1) && letter!='*')` here, we check whether `scanf()` successfully scanned or not and whether the scanned element is `*` or not

---

**sample input :**

```
1
2
a
t
3
*
```

**output :**

```
Type one letter of alphabet and following letters will appear (lowercase): 

1, invalid entry.
try again

2, invalid entry.
try again

a, valid entry!

b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 

t, valid entry!

u v w x y z 

3, invalid entry.
try again

*   
ended
```

Comment: Just take away the letter != '*' in the while conditions?

Comment: @Mad just add a `break;` at the end of `if` block in the `while` loop and yes (**additionally**, you can remove `letter != '*'` if you want to stop after correct input)

Comment: @Mad I've mentioned in comments *(in the code)* where to place the `break;`

Comment: Cherubim can you help me with the code I just posted and asked about banking and menus?

Answer (score 3):

In this line:

```
for (letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; ++letter){
```

why do you start at `a`? Dont you want to start one after the user input letter, which is stored in `letter`?

So do that:

```
for (++letter; letter <= 'z'; ++letter){
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to increment the letter variable  by 1 in for loop parameter:

```
for (letter += 1; letter <= 'z'; ++letter){         
    printf("%c ", letter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX 122

int
main(void) {
    char letter;
    int i;

    printf("Type one letter of the alphabet(lowercase): ");
    scanf("%c", &letter);

    if (islower(letter)) {

        printf("%c, valid entry!\n\n", letter);

        for (i = letter + 1; i <= MAX; i++) {
            printf("%c", i);
        }

    } else {
        printf("%c, invalid entry.\n\n", letter);
    }

    return 0;
}
```